# How to make the contents of an HTML table fit within their cells?

Tags: javascript, css

I have an HTML table whose contents sometimes don't fit inside the specified sizes of their respective cells. In all browsers, the default behavior is to make the cells expand to fit their contents, either vertically or horizontally. Instead, I'd like to *visually* trim the contents to fit their cells like this:

[image: Text trimming example]

I am using [a jQuery plugin](http://datatables.net) that allows the user to sort the table by any of its fields. For this reason, it is very important that the actual contents be never trimmed, just displayed as if they had been trimmed.

How could I do that using standard technologies only (CSS and JavaScript)?

Comment: If you're getting the horizontal scroll you may want to reduce the width a little further or increase the height of that cell...

Comment: @Kenneth: Sorry, I stated it incorrectly. My table *has* an horizonal scroll (I designed it that way), but it gets removed when I use `table-layout: fixed`.

Comment: How about you show a jsFiddle example for your table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a css property named [`text-overflow`](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/textoverflow.html) which accomplishes this.

If you use it in conjunction with `white-space: nowrap`, you can achieve what you're trying to do.

Here's a demo on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u7QuA/

I had to wrap the contents of the td in a span because the css properties wouldn't work on the td for some reason.

Comment: Yes, after wrapping the contents of the `td` inside a `span`, it worked like a charm! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can set a width for all your cells and restrict a specific number of character in JavaScript which must be displayed. For example you put a JavaScript condition for string have more than 15 characters using the `substring(0, 15)` and add "..." at the end of the string.

I don't know if it's the best solution but it should work.

Comment: My table has sortable columns and your proposed solution messes with the sorting.